# C# Reflection and Getting Properties

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have the following dummy class structure and I am trying to find out how to get the properties from each instance of the class People in PeopleList.  I know how to get the properties from a single instance of People but can't for the life of me figure out how to get it from PeopleList.  I am sure this is really straightforward but can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public class Example
{
    public class People
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private int _age;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; }
        }

        public People()
        {

        }

        public People(string name, int age)
        {
            this._name = name;
            this._age = age;
        }
    }

    public class PeopleList : List<People>
    {
        public static void DoStuff()
        {
             PeopleList newList = new PeopleList();

            // Do some stuff

             newList.Add(new People("Tim", 35));
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862783/setting-properties-of-an-object-through-reflection-with-different-properties-type

Comment: What do you mean you can't get them from `PeopleList`? There are no properties in your example, other than the standard `Count` and `Capacity`...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Are there different classes that may inherit from `People` and you want to get those properties, or do you simply wish to get the various values of the items within the list (if so, I don't understand why you need reflection for this). Could you add an example of how you intend to use this data (pseudo code should be good enough).

Comment: Why would you need relection for this?

Comment: Sorry, not a well thought out example.  What I intended to do and this maybe wrong too, is have a generic method where I pass PeopleList in and T could be PeopleList.  Then I would loop through through each instance of PeopleList getting the properties of People and it's values.  T could be any class inheriting from List<T>.  I hope this helps?

Comment: you seem confused. In your generic method.. you can loop over the elements since you would have a generic constraint where T : List<T>
Now within the loop/iterator, you have individual elements of the list - you can therefore apply your reflection skills to get at the values. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I don't think you missed anything I am just still learning about generics, only been at this a year and half.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Still not 100% sure of what you want, but this quick bit of code (untested) might get you on the right track (or at least help clarify what you want).

```
void ReportValue(String propName, Object propValue);

void ReadList<T>(List<T> list)
{
  var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
  foreach(T item in list)
  {
    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
      ReportValue(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item));
    }
  }
}
```

c# should be able to work out that 'PeopleList' inherits from 'List' and handle that fine, but if you need to have 'PeopleList' as the generic type, then this should work:

```
void ReadList<T>(T list) where T : System.Collections.IList
{
  foreach (Object item in list)
  {
    var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
      ReportValue(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item, null));
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this will actually process properties in derived types within the list as well.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I intended on doing.  However, how would you go about it if (List<T> list) was (T obj) where T is PeopleList?  Or is that not the way to go?  Is it just better to use (List<T> list)? This is what I am struggling with.

Comment: @Nathan - you could just use `IEnumerable<T>`, since I'm *guessing* that `PeopleList` is `IEnumerable<Person>`.