# Passing class as parameter in C# and then wanting to access property of class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to refactor some code as I have about 7 occurrences of code like this:

```
List<RHEvent> eventResults = DBConnection.Table<RHEvent>().Where(t => (int)t.PreferredImage == ID).ToList();
foreach (RHEvent result in eventResults)
{
    result.PreferredImage = 0;
    DBConnection.Update(result);
}
```

where RHEvent changes to different class names through the different occurrences.

I've started to try and write more generalised code but I'm hitting a snag. Here is what I've got so far:

```
private void ResetPreferredImage<T>(int ID) where T: new()
{
    List<T> results = DBConnection.Table<T>().Where(t => (int)t.PreferredImage == ID).ToList();
}
```

The problem is that the compiler doesn't like PreferredImage because it cannot identify it in the abstract class.

Is there a way to reassure the compiler that the property exists or is it simply not possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Philip

Comment: Your classes would all need to implement a common interface that defined the `PreferredImage` property.

Comment: Either an interface or inheritance from some base class that defines PreferredImage.  Of course if your using some kind of ORM you might have auto generated POCOs which would potentially make that a little more difficult.  I wouldn't recommend a reflection approach, but it would be possible to do it that way.

Comment: are u using any kind of ORM

Comment: cgotberg, all of the classes involved here are derived from a common base class but that isn't helping me because the compiler doesn't know that T is going to be based off that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
private void ResetPreferredImage<T>(int ID) where T : BaseClass,new()
        {
            List<T> results = DBConnection.Table<T>().Where(t => (int)t.PreferredImage == ID).ToList(); 
        }
```

Now the Compiler will recognize the PreferredImage Property  as a property of a base class

Answer (score 0):

If they do not implement a base class which exposes a `PrefferedImage` property, your only other option would be to use reflector.

See [C# Reflection and Getting Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762531/c-sharp-reflection-and-getting-properties)