# Search and Find methods and properties in namespaces C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When you type something in Visual Studio you could use IntelliSense ability to find some available and visible methods or properties in the appeared list.

That's good, But what about when you don't know the property you want, is the child of what property?

For example you have a textbox and you know you can change its back color.
you type TextBox and in the list of appeared IntelliSense, you won't find it. Because you should Type "TextBox.Element." then you will see Back color here in the list.

Hope I'm clear enough. I need to search and find the properties and methods related to an object. If I need the padding property of a textbox then it show me it is located in "TextBox.Sizing.Info.Padding".

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can be useful, right-click on the reference in solution explorer, and then select "View in Object Browser". There you will see all Hierarchies with a search box to find your special name.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need something like MSDN documentation.

For example, If I open [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) for WPF TextBox element, you can simply search by "color" word and find `Foreground` property.

Another option may be "Object Browser" in Visual Studio (View -> Object Browser), but there you can only search in namespace/class/method/property name.

Answer (score 0):

While this is usually covered in the documentation (i.e. MSDN pages, library readmes, etc), you can also find an object's properties at runtime with Reflection.

This is done using the GetProperties() method.  I think the rest of what you will need to know is explained in  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762531/c-sharp-reflection-and-getting-properties).