# WinRT C++ Create a shallow copy of an object

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

According to Platform::Object Class docs ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh748265.aspx ) there is a method to create a shallow copy:

[MemberwiseClone] method
Creates a shallow copy of the current Object.

How to use it ? I have tried object->MemberwiseClone(), Object::MemberiwseClone(), without success ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such member function; the documentation is incorrect.  If you want to make one of your types copyable, you can implement a constructor that makes a copy or a member function that returns a copy.

(I'll inform the appropriate people so that the documentation is corrected.)

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically access to each property name and value ?

Comment: In .NET you can use reflection.  But "copying" an object often means more than just cloning members.  If you are implementing your type in C++ and you want to implement a memberwise copy, wrap the members up in a single class and have your runtime class have a single data member of that type.  Your copy operation can then simply copy that one data member.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862783/setting-properties-of-an-object-through-reflection-with-different-properties-typ?rq=1